# changing value in python

Tags: python, text

I'm scraping some info from a site using python and one of the value's has to be in the name of the file.

for this specific part I can't seem to get it to print right.
In the API there is a line like this:

> `BroadcastDate = 20100401`

now I want to print this value like this.

> `01.04.2010`

I know there is a lot possible in Python with text but I can't seem to figure it out or find anything on Google.

you smart guys probably know if its possible and how.
if something is unclear or you have a question, let me know!

**EDIT**
so I got the following piece of code which should need to work in my head but I dont get a response:

```
b = "20100104"
print((b[7:8]).(b[5:6]).(b[1:4]))
```

Comment: If you get the date into a string, you can use slices to reformat it as you want.

Comment: Hint: `date[0:4]` will extract the year, `date[5:7]` will get the month.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the help I will look in to slices. I think I will figure it out.
I was aware of it not being a free coding service, it was in response to me previous topics where I already provided some code. and I was just looking for a pointer in the right direction, which I got now thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Barmar your awnser put me in the right direction.

This worked:

```
b = "20100103"
year = (b[0:4])
month = (b[4:6])
day = (b[6:9])
print ((day) +(".") +(month) +(".") +(year))
```